# Should I use multiple CADisplayLink objects for each cell in collection view or use a single displayLink and forward callbacks

Tags: ios, objective-c, cadisplaylink

What's more efficient with `CADisplayLink`? Having multiple instances, one for each cell, or having a single instance and forwarding calls to each cell?

Comment: Please explain your problem. Moreover, the point of the `CADisplayLink`is to be able to draw with each refresh of the screen.

Comment: Yes, my purpose is exactly that. Want to update each cell after screen refresh, so I'm asking if there should be a CADisplayLink for each cell or just one instance

Comment: do u want to reload tableView using displayLink?

Comment: it shouldn't make a difference. but you can profile it to find out the truth...